# How to retrieve time in second

Tags: solidity, remix

I need to retrieve time from depositTime and now in seconds

Example Deposit Time 3/10/2020 18:00:05 and now 3/10/2020 18:00:08

Output: 3 second.

```
 uint256 RetrieveSecondsTime = invest.depositTime - now ??
```

I don't have idea how to do this.

Comment: I think now - invest.depositTime or block.time - invest.depostiTime... or you will get a negative number which is not unit256
.. is invest a struct? give us more info please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All datetime values are stored as integers in Solidity. The `block.timestamp` (also known as `now` but that name will be deprecated in future versions) is the amount of seconds since year 1970: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=timestamp#block-and-transaction-properties

So to calculate the amount of seconds between two datetimes you can simply deduct one from the other, like in your example. Note that you can't get an accuracy of 3 seconds like in your example because the most accurate timestamp you can get is the block's timestamp (`block.timestamp`) and one block is about every 15 seconds.